# Joining polygons to polylines based off specific point in polyline being within polygon

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

I am trying to join a polyline feature class and a polygon feature class. The polylines will always have at least their first point in a polygon, and each polyline consists of exactly three points. There is a chance of the last point of the polyline being in another polygon, but I do not want to join that polygon. There will be multiple polylines from within each polygon and I want to join these.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(lines, polygons, linesAndPolygons, #, #, #, "POLYGON_CONTAINS_FIRST_POINT_OF_POLYLINE")
```

There is of course no explicit match option like above, but that is what I need. Any ideas? I was considering making a new feature class of points from the polylines, joining those to the polygons, and then joining the polylines to the points, but it seems like there should be a simpler way.

Comment: Your method is what I would have come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have Advanced license level:

[Add fields](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000047000000) to your polyline feature class to store coordinates (Double) and a join-id field (long) then [Calculate Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/) using Python parser and [geometry object](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Polyline/000v000000n2000000/):

```
JoinID = !FID!
FromX = !SHAPE!.firstPoint.X
FromY = !SHAPE!.firstPoint.Y
```

This will attribute your polylines with their start coordinate whitch you can make into a point layer with [Create Feature Class from XY Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006z000000).

If you do have an advanced license use [Feature Vertices to Points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003p000000) (start) to get the points from the first vertex.. it is a good idea to calculate the JoinID before doing that. Vertex points will have the same attributes as the source line making joining easier.

Either [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) or [Intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000) the layer with your polygons. Your resulting points will contain (amongst other things):

- ID of polygon
- JoinID of polyline
- Depending on match_option in Spatial Join or join_attributes in
  Intersect possibly all the attributes of both.

Join the polylines to the joined points with [Join by Attributes](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000064000000)...

These are the python/geoprocesing tools, if you wish to do this interactively you can use Calculate Field etc.. in exactly the same manner.

Comment: Very elaborate, but he rejects this approach in his question

Comment: @FelixIP he does not reject this approach, he considers it but postulates there must be a simper way... This approach shows that it's fairly simple.

Comment: Well I ended up just doing it this way and it seems to have worked. Wish there was a "FIRST_POINT_IN..." option though, that would certainly be handy... Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Creating start point etc is logical and rather simple, not sure why not using it. This is untested but might worth a try:

1. Intersect polylines with polygons, output - line
2. Remove duplicates from result of unique line ids
3. Join remaining segments to parent line layer

**UPDATE:**
Tested, doesn't work. It picks line part from smaller polygon [FID]